# My code supported with http but not with the https. It shows that java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, http, ssl, https

I tried to send a `GET` request to the server(containing the details about the devices) and take the response from it. Inside the response should be the details about the devices. Those details are `device Id` and `device Type`.
Follow is my code.

I had replaced the Id address by using xxx.xx... sorry about it.

I tried once in `http` port(8482).
This implementations is works for it. But actually I want to use this program for `https` port(8120)

Then what should I do for this code to taken the support of `https`

```
void callConfigEndPoint() {
    String host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    String httpPort = "8482";
    String deviceToken = "7645221";
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    String endpointUrl = "http://"+host+":"+httpPort+"/api/device-mgt-config/v1.0";
    try {
        URL urlObject = new URL(endpointUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("token", deviceToken);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        String deviceId = jsonObj.get("deviceId").toString();
        String deviceType = jsonObj.get("deviceType").toString();
        System.out.println("deviceId                      =>" + deviceId);
        System.out.println("deviceType                    =>" + deviceType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please consider that, I had removed the import section from this

Comment: I see you use `HttpURLConnection`, have you tried working with the `HttpsURLConnection`?

Comment: No. Are you state that is it will be success? Can you change this code for https?

Comment: Never personally tried, but since `HttpsURLConnection` is a subclass of `HttpURLConnection` I think it will work without editing the code elsewhere. Have you tried?